# Configure subversion to start SSH tunnel automatically for HTTP-only SVN server

Tags: ssh, svn, http, tunnel

We have an SVN server accessible with HTTP (and only HTTP) running on a firewalled port on our development system:

```
dev $ svn checkout http://localhost:1234/proj/trunk
```

On my workstation, I created a tunnel in my ssh configuration so that I can export from the repository into a staging and deployment location.

```
bob $ tail -n 3 ~/.ssh/config
Host svn-tun
  HostName dev
  LocalForward 8080 dev:1234
bob $ ssh -f -N svn-tun
bob $ svn export --force http://localhost:8080/proj/trunk .
```

What I want to do now is configure subversion (I think) to start the tunnel for me, use HTTP to localhost:8080, and then close the tunnel. I would like it to be as easy as:

> $ svn export --force **foo**://**dev-tun**/proj/trunk .

Unfortunately I am not a clever man.

Comment: Since you are already logging onto your development system using SSH to forward the port, couldn't you directly access the repository through SSH and bypass the web server?

Comment: i will edit it to note that HTTP is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know subversion doesn't support SSH tunnels.

You could write a script to start the tunnel and do an export:

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh svn-tun sleep 1 &
svn export --force http://localhost:8080/proj/trunk .
wait
```